# É possível adicionar dependências manualmente no VueJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Estou iniciando meu primeiro projeto usando a *FrameWork Vue.JS*, sei que pelo Vue UI é possível abrir o *Vue CLI* nos permitindo adicionar plugins e dependências no projeto.

Tenho dependências que foram customizadas por mim mesmo e preciso adiciona-las no meu projeto, isso seria possível? Creio que sim, portanto como fazer isso? E me desculpem caso esse tipo de dúvida não se encaixe nesta área do fórum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu consegui descobrir aqui como faz, e para quem tiver a mesma dificuldade, vou explicar!

Todos as suas dependências devem ser inseridas dentro da pasta *public* como na imagem abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em seguida devemos fazer a seguinte referência em nossos componentes que irá usar as dependências

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E por fim deve ir arquivo *index.html* e invocar as dependências da seguinte forma passando o argumento `<%= BASE_URL %>`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você já pode selecionar sua resposta como definitiva.